# Como dizer "brain-storming" em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, estrangeirismos

*[Brainstorming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstorming)* é uma palavra inglesa que significa mais ou menos "pensar e contribuir ideias espontâneas, em grupo para procurar soluções para um problema".
[Segundo o dicionário Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/brainstorm):

> Técnica para desenvolvimento de novas ideias ou resolução de problemas, baseada numa discussão em que várias pessoas fazem muitas sugestões para que sejam escolhidas as melhores ou uma fusão delas.
>
> > "brainstorm", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2020,  [consultado em 29-01-2020].

[Segundo o Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainstorm), "*brainstorming*" é:

> to try to solve a problem or come up with new ideas by having a discussion that includes all members of a group : to discuss a problem or issue and suggest solutions and ideas .

---

Então:

- Existe alguma expressão portuguesa que possa ser usada no lugar deste estrangeirismo?

Exemplos de uso:

> - A equipa de engenharia juntou-se para tentar *fazer brainstorm* de ideias sobre como conseguir construir a pala arquitetada pelo Siza.
> - A turma juntou-se num *brainstorm* aceso sobre como conseguir convencer os mais velhos a deixá-los jogar também.
> - Querendo evitar a insolvência a todo o custo, o Conselho Administrativo convidou a comissão de trabalhadores para um *brainstorming* de ideias "fora-da-caixa".

Comment: A palavra já foi aceita, então....discussão coletiva

Comment: Não percebo, @Lambie . Estás a sugerir "discussão coletiva" como uma resposta?

Comment: Sim, é isso que estou dizendo. :) ou seja provocar uma tempestade cerebral de ideias.

Answer (score 3):

Pode-se utilizar equivalentemente a expressão portuguesa *"chuva de ideias"*:

> - A equipa de engenharia juntou-se para tentar ter uma **chuva de ideias** sobre como conseguir construir a pala arquitetada pelo Siza.
> - A turma juntou-se numa **chuva de ideias** acesa sobre como conseguir convencer os mais velhos a deixá-los jogar também.
> - Querendo evitar a insolvência a todo o custo, o Conselho Administrativo convidou a comissão de trabalhadores para uma **chuva
>     de ideias** "fora-da-caixa".

É possível que esta expressão tenha nascido de uma tentativa de tradução - literal - de *brainstorm*.

Comment: Olha que eu nunca tinha ouvido falar em "chuva de ideias". Essa é de facto boa! Mas se me falares de "chuva de estrelas" penso logo na Catarina Furtado.

Comment: Ui, foste ao fundo do baú buscar essa, já nem me lembrava!! lmao

Comment: Francamente, o chuva de ideias é criada pelo grupo, um grupo não se junta nela....chuva de ideias "fora da caixa" me dar dores no corpo inteiro....:)

Comment: Apenas apliquei os exemplos que estavam na questão. Claro que a tradução não é perfeita, seria necessário parafrasear/reescrever um pouco as frases iniciais para que a expressão estivesse melhor aplicada. Mas a questão aqui era saber que expressão portuguesa pode ser usada no lugar de "brainstorm" e a melhor aproximação é, de facto, "chuva de ideias".

Comment: Se for questão de literalismo/literalidade, provocar uma tempestade cerebral de ideias. chuva não funciona. brain rain?

Comment: Não é uma questão de literalidade. A expressão "chuva de ideias" existe mesmo e é utilizada em Portugal como substituto de "brainstorm" - ou seja, não estou a sugerir uma tradução "nova", apenas a apontar uma expressão que existe, e que provavelmente derivou do estrangeirismo. Já agora, nesse caso, escreveria antes "provocar uma chuva de ideias"

Answer (score 0):

Podemos começar por reparar, que o "brainstorming" não é necessáriamente colectivo, a palavra é frequentemente usada para actividade individual. Pode ter o sentido de diálogo em grupo, ou monólogo interior. Mas classifica sempre um esforço de reflexão ou resolução.

O sucesso da palavra "brainstorming", medido pela proliferação do seu uso, deve-se a ser um recurso estílistico. Associa a imagem (ou metáfora) de intensa actividade intelectual a uma tempestade, e associa a imagem do cérebro ao pensamento. É uma palavra composta por justaposição de duas imagens.

Mas devemos fazer o contraste com a palavra do Português usada em ciência e engenharia:

> **Análise:**
>
> 1. Exame minucioso de uma coisa em cada uma das suas partes.
> 2. Separação dos princípios componentes de um corpo ou substância.
> 3. [Figurado]  Exame que se faz de uma produção intelectual. = CRÍTICA, ESTUDO
> 4. [Matemática]  Parte da matemática que estuda os conceitos de continuidade, convergência e limite.
> 5. [Filosofia]  Método de exame pelo qual se sobe das consequências ou efeitos aos princípios ou causas.
>
> ["análise", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa](https://dicionario.priberam.org/an%C3%A1lise) [em linha], 2008-2020, [consultado em 29-01-2020].

É uma erro associarmos qualquer seriedade à palavra "brainstorming". A palavra pode simplesmente descrever um cavaquear com todos a atirarem bitaites para o ar. Ou um ensimesmado sonho a deambular absorto por quimeras. Até porque um verdadeiro trabalho de análise e reflexão é por excelência prolongado, lento, demorado.

Por fim, a expressão mais próxima seria: "(momento de) intenso trabalho intelectual (individual ou colectivo)". Mas isso já são 3 palavras, significativo trabalho intelectual que é de facto aliviado pelo "brainstorming"...O brainstorming em semântica anda perto de uma dor de cabeça, ou um analgésico facilitista.

Eram estes mecanismos das *palavras compostas* Inglesas que ficaram denomiados por [Orwellian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orwellian) ao jeito [Newspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak).

> Então:
>
> Existe alguma expressão portuguesa que possa ser usada no lugar deste estrangeirismo?

Reunião (de estudo, preliminar ou informal) para troca/levantamento de ideias.

**EDIT:** Eu não queria dizer isto, mas é possivel que a expressão "diarreia mental" tenha sido uma mímica satírica do "brainstorming". Parece-me plausível, nunca se sabe...

Comment: «o "brainstorming" não é necessáriamente colectivo» Não é a minha experiência, nem encontro validação disso em dicionários. Podes fundamentar? Talvez seja suficiente citar exemplos desse uso.

Comment: @ANeves a ler posts aleatórios na NET reparei em proporção à frequência do vocábulo, que muitos autores usam o termo para escrever sobre sí próprios quando estão sozinhos a pensar. Sou-te sincero nisto, quanto ao uso prático do termo parece-me ser tendência generalizada aplicá-lo ao individual, independentmente da definição que o dicionário dê ao neologismo. Éh pá, são aqueles palavrões Ingleses que nem os Anglófonos sabem o que dizem...

Comment: @ANeves estou a escangalhar-me de tanto rir sozinho vai para perto de 10 minutos... :) este foi o melhor post até à data...deliciosa descarga de endorfinas.

Comment: Ótimo, que o que a faz falta é animar a malta!

Comment: a palavra é frequentemente usada para actividade individual=FALSE [coding word]. É um atividade em grupo ou coletivo. Credo. :)

Comment: Ahhh, o meu antagonista :) muito me impacienta ser contrariado. Seja, concedo. Tens razão @Lambie (mas é só desta vez, porque eu deixo).

Comment: É só ler o verbete em qualquer dicionário inglês.

Comment: @Lambie na [na wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstorming#Individual_brainstorming),
na [sciencedirect](https://sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/019188699500009U),
na [APA](https://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2F0022-3514.61.3.392) (a APA em especial tem um certo peso). Sou levado a apontar usos menos comuns do vocábulo, também para evidenciar que seguindo estrangeirmos acabamos por lexicalizar disparates, é expressivo ter um substantivo que dispensa uma frase para dizer o mesmo, mas é redutor da nossa expressão.

Comment: brainstorming is brainstorming and every educated English speaker knows what it means. There are no less common usages of it.

Comment: @Lambie I am forced to call into question what "educated" really is, especially in the case of modern English neologisms. The term was coined in 1939 and we have examined it here sufficiently. I provided proof the word can be applied to individual activity (thus I accept the challenge twice issued). I will say this: my stance is profoundly ethnic, by questioning if not outright rejecting any foreign word I can't immediately express in my native language. And so I take, a conservative [ethnolinguistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnolinguistics) position, in regard to my own language space.

Comment: Let's be politer, yes? Thank you for understanding. There's [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/falatorio) if needed, to discuss and clear any misunderstandings.